# Google Directions API, why leg is needed?

Tags: api, direction

Why are legs needed in Google Directions API?  What will be problems when Route is just a list of Waypoints?

Comment: Every response contains a legs array. If you don't have any waypoints, there will only be one leg. You will receive (your total number of points, including origin and destination) -1 legs in any response from the API.

Comment: Thank you @ecg8. You just state the fact of Direction API. What is the reason to have legs? Why not just make Route an array of Waypoints? Empty array for no Waypoints.

Comment: If the the client app requested some intermediate way points on the route in the request to the Directions API, then the app may need to know some details about the *segments* of the final route according to the input way points. Legs represents these segments